# Java Batch(JSR-352) and Session Context CDI

Tags: java, batch-processing, jsr352

I am using the java Batch (JSR-352), it is possible to work with a session bean inside it? I needed to have a Bean with @SessionScope annotation, to catch some information in it, that to differentiate the type of User that is running the batch process.

It's possivel use a Session Context CDI inside the specification ? If is possible how is the best pratice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the session isn't going to propagate from the thread starting the job via JobOperator to the execution thread. I don't recall if this is under discussion in the CDI specification still or a settled matter, but for now you can't.